# Composer run-script of nested packages

Tags: git, composer-php

I have composer project without code but with list of dependencies. I want to run `composer install` for download all dependent packages and run some bash commands into each one after it.

My `composer.json`:

```json
{
    "name": "testmain/testmain",
    "description": "testmain",
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "repositories": [
      {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "testsub/testsub1",
                "description": "testsub/testsub1",
                "version": "master",
                "source": {
                    "url": "https://github.com/testsub/testsub1",
                    "type": "git",
                    "reference": "master"
                },
                "scripts": {
                    "post-install-cmd": [
                        "make",
                        "make install"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "testsub/testsub2",
                "description": "testsub/testsub2",
                "version": "master",
                "source": {
                    "url": "https://github.com/testsub/testsub2",
                    "type": "git",
                    "reference": "master"
                },
                "scripts": {
                    "post-install-cmd": [
                        "make",
                        "make install"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "testsub/testsub1": "master",
        "testsub/testsub2": "master"
    }
}
```

The problem is in running `scripts` sequence of nested packages, all scripts are ignored by Composer.

Comment: Creating a composer plugin might be your best option here: https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/plugins.md#creating-a-plugin

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately, **it is not possible to execute any non-ROOT** scripts (in meaning non-root `composer.json`), as mentioned in [documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md#what-is-a-script-):

> Note: Only scripts defined in the root package's composer.json are executed. If a dependency of the root package specifies its own scripts, Composer does not execute those additional scripts.

Answer (score 5):

As Tomas stated, it is not possible to *automatically* call non-ROOT scripts. But you can enable the user to call them manually. This is not applicable in all situations, but good in others.

If you have the following in `vendor/johndoe/mypackage/composer.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "nameOfScript": "\\johndoe\\mypackage\\Scripts::invoke"
}
```

In the `composer.json` of your root directory put the following:

```
"scripts": {
    "myFancyScript": [
        "@putenv COMPOSER=vendor/johndoe/mypackage/composer.json",
        "@composer nameOfScript"
    ]
}
```

Then the user can call `composer myFancyScript` from your root directory and the static function `invoke()` in the package `johndoe/mypackage` is executed.